# Content Query Webpart (CQWP) Pagination in SPO

Tags: jquery, content-query-web-part, xslt

I am trying to paginate a CQWP results set but I am struggling with XSLT.

Is there an easy way to do it? Should I work directly on the ItemStyle.xsl? Should I use jQuery instead?

I can't believe this feature is not within the webparts settings.

Thank you all for your help!

pR

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it's important to avoid using the CQWP in 365 when possible. You will experience performance issues due to the way caching is handled in that environment vs On Premises. The Content by Search Web Part is generally the way to go and is the official recommendation (unless you are needing to respect audiences).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the article for [Paging in Content Query Webpart](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/paging-content-query-web-part/).
This article may help you get more details to achieve paging in your webpart.

Also you can take a look at this Codeplex project of [OOTB SharePoint CQWP Paging](https://cqwppaging.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#PagingTemplates.xslt). It has the XSLT manipulation for paging.

If you can install the WSP Solution, then here is another link: [IMTech Content Query Webpart](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-2010-content-query-web-part-paging/), which will allow you to have paging in Content query webpart.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Pradip. I had already read them all. The first and the last article require the installation of a custom wsp. Regarding the one in the middle, as soon I as copy and paste the xls code into  ItemStyle.xsl I get an error. Thank you anyway for your prompt response!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a good reason why you are not using either the PnP Search web parts (for Modern) or Content Search for Classic?
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/using-content-search-web-part-instead-of-content-query-web-part-to-improve-perfo

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-solutions/blob/master/solutions/ModernSearch/react-search-refiners/README.md